# .htaccess; Too many redirects if two different redirects in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've two types of URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/?content=contact_form.php
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/?content=product.php&id=20
```

I changed my whole URL system like this:

```
http://www.example.com/file/contact_form
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/product/I-m-the-title/20
```

Of course I made 301 redirect with `.htaccess` to tell Google and co. the new URL.

I made it like this:

```
# Rewrite URLs

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(ignore)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ /?content=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?content=$1.php&title=$2&id=$3 [L]


# Redirect old URL to new URL

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^content=contact\_form\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/file/contact_form? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^content=product\.php&class=I-m-the-title$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/I-m-the-title/Test/20? [R=301,L]
```

My problem:

It's perfectly working for: `http://www.example.com/?content=product.php&id=20`

But for `http://www.example.com/?content=contact_form.php` I'm getting the message that it couldn't get opened because of too much redirect.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I hope anybody can help me soon because I have to fix it before Google misinterprets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule cause an infinite loop because it is rewriting your uri to the same location again and again overriding your internal and external redirects.. To fix the Rewrite loop, add the following at the top of your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```